# Remove Most Frequently Used Apps Container from Apps menu

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, menu

In Android 6.0.1 I got this unnecessary feature which displays most frequently used apps on top of all other applications. 
 I don't need it (You can see on the pic the top 4 apps underlined). Is it possible to disable this feature at all?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove the most used app bar follow the steps :

1. Open Google Now ;
2. Open the sidebar (hamburger menu or slide from the left) ;
3. Click the "Settings" button ;
4. Scroll down to the **Home screen** section
5. Toggle the option "App Suggestions".

Source : [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/3oupvn/anyway_to_remove_the_most_used_app_bar_on_the_new/).

Answer (score 7):

There was recently an update (Android 7.1.2) that makes the previous answer incorrect, the new directions are as follows:

1. Press and hold on the home screen until this dialogue appears:[image]

   2. Then simply press the settings icon and change the one that says app suggestions.

Source: experimenting

Comment: Oct 2019: This is the answer that still works:
Hold home screen > Home settings > Suggestions > Apps (disable)